# Meteor jQuery DataTable increasing size

Tags: jquery, meteor, datatable

I'm using the jQuery DataTables plugin with a fair amount of success on Meteor (not using any packages).
I have a certain table that monitors a collection that is constantly being inserted. What happens on a new insertion is the datatable just adds a new line and keeps on growing indefinitely, ignoring the page limit (10 rows per page, when this happens it just adds 11, 12, 13...).

My table structure is as follows:

```
                    <table id="data-table-1">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Time</th>
                                <th>Data</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {{#each getData}}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{unixtime}}</td>
                                <td>{{Data}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            {{/each}}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

If I could listen to the event that adds a new `<tr>` I guess I could just redraw the table.

Comment: Can we see some code?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to help without seeing your code. However, please see this information from [the Docs](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html):

> New rows can be added to a DataTable very easily using the row.add() API method. Simply call the API function with the data that is to be used for the new row (be it an array or object). Multiple rows can be added using the rows.add() method (note the plural). Data can be likewise be updated with the row().data() and row().remove() methods.
>
> **Note that in order to see the new row in the table you must call the draw() method**, which is easily done through the chaining that the DataTables API makes use of.

Also, since you are using Meteor, have a look at

https://github.com/LumaPictures/meteor-jquery-datatables

and

https://jquery-datatables.meteor.com/examples/reactive-query

I've not used Meteor myself, but this looks like what you need.

Comment: What I'm trying to do now is to find the event that adds a new <tr> to the table. If I could listen to that event and then redraw the table I guess I'd be  OK...

Comment: I've spent some time using a similar package, tabular, and I know I could make it work with the package. It's just that my project has loads of tables implemented this way, and once I add a datatable package it usually screws with the formatting of other tables.
I'm confident there's a simple way to do this using just the plugin, I just wasn't able to find it yet.